# How to get a specific element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the `div` element which has the class `repeat`. So I tried this, but it shows `undefined`.

```
var data = '<div class="test form-group col-xs-6 repeat" id="repeat_py">\n <div class="kv col-lg-2">index:\n<pre class="num">0</pre></div>\n<div><span class="kv">value: <pre class="num">m</pre></span></div></div>'

alert($(data).find('div.repeat').html())
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgf9nyn0/14/)

Comment: You know that `data` is a string in this context, right? So you need to parse it

Comment: tried this `alert($(data).html().find('div.repeat').html())`

Comment: Simpler is to append in body using $('body').append(data) and then find or simpler $('.repeat')

Comment: @AdamAzad: He/she *is* parsing it: `$(data)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of `.find()`

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
 $(data).filter('div.repeat').html()
```

```js
var data = '<div class="test form-group col-xs-6 repeat" id="repeat_py">\n <div class="kv col-lg-2">index:\n<pre class="num">0</pre></div>\n<div><span class="kv">value: <pre class="num">m</pre></span></div></div>'

alert($(data).filter('div.repeat').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thought `find` helps to find the corresponding element. Then what's the use of `find`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, `find()` searches in descendant of elements, where as `filter()` filters in the elements i.e. `$(data)`

Answer (score 1):

replace `find` with `filter`

```
alert($(data).filter('div.repeat').html())
```

find looks for children, filter looks at the sibling level

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var data = '<div class="test form-group col-xs-6 repeat" id="repeat_py">\n <div class="kv col-lg-2">index:\n<pre class="num">0</pre></div>\n<div><span class="kv">value: <pre class="num">m</pre></span></div></div>';
 
var HTMLobject = $('<div/>').html(data);
console.log(HTMLobject.find('div.repeat').html());
alert(HTMLobject.find('div.repeat').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try with this `alert($(data).html());`

Answer (score 0):

you are just missing wrapper class here that's why you got an error as undefined

try the following code

```html
 var data = '<div><div class="test form-group col-xs-6 repeat" id="repeat_py">\n <div class="kv col-lg-2">index:\n<pre class="num">0</pre></div>\n<div><span class="kv">value: <pre class="num">m</pre></span></div></div></div>'
alert($(data).find('div.repeat').html())
```

This give me perfect alert

Answer (score 0):

```
ALternate solution:

var data = '<div class="test form-group col-xs-6 repeat" id="repeat_py">\n <div class="kv col-lg-2">index:\n<pre class="num">0</pre></div>\n<div><span class="kv">value: <pre class="num">m</pre></span></div></div>'
$('body').append(data);
alert($('body').find('div.repeat').html());

Fiddle link
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fgf9nyn0/18/